# Clear the Browser Cache of React app after every new deployment

Tags: reactjs, apache, jenkins-pipeline, browser-cache, cache-control

[I have added Cache Headers but Its doesnt remove my Browser Cache. Can anyone please help how to do that??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDfP2.png)

<VirtualHost *:443>

```
    ServerName <ip-address>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/build

    Include conf/headers.conf

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/sites-available/cert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/sites-available/ssl.key

    <Directory /var/www/html/build/>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many different browsers, there is no 100% reliable way for you to control what a clients browser stores in it cache. You can set headers on your servers response which tell a web browser that it should dump old files from it's cache and request new ones after a predefined period but this is only a recommendation, the browser may choose to ignore it, after all you do not control the browser software a client is using.

Set browser cache control headers in your Apache config file something like this...

```
# here we are telling the browser to request new files for specific images after 604800 seconds or 7 days, i.e. dump the cache if files are more than 7 days old 
        
          <FilesMatch "bird.jpg|dog.jpg|noob.jpg|fish.jpg|rabbit.jpg|cow.jpg">
                  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public, must-revalidate"
          </FilesMatch>
        
# here we are telling the browser to request new files for specific file types after 86400 seconds or 1 day
        
        <FilesMatch ".(css|js|ttf|ico)$">
                Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400, public, must-revalidate"
        </FilesMatch>
```

If you are just looking for a quick way to clear the cache on google chrome on your own pc you can install a browser plugin to to that such as https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-cache-refresh/njacldedajpdoofkhpfckdkgcahjlfkj